# ISO_8583 MESSAGE PACKING

Tags: c

I am trying to pack an `iso 8583` message below

`00 2F 60 01 23 06 00 08 00 20 20 01 00 00 c0 00 
00 92 00 00 00 00 12 01 23 48 30 30 30 30 30 30 
39 53 31 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 35`

here when i extracted bit fields from bit map i got the fields `3,11,24,41,42` in which field `3` and `11` are in `N6 format`, field `24` is in `N3 format` and field `41,42` are in `ANS format..`

Before sending the packet the fields which are in numeric format need to be change in BCD format by the function

```
enter code here

void vAscii2BCD(unsigned char *pucSrc, unsigned char *pucDst, int inSize)
{
for (; inSize > 0; inSize -= 2, pucDst++) 
{
    if(!memcmp(pucSrc, "3D", 2))
    {
        pucSrc += 2;
        *pucDst = '=';

    }
    else
    {
        *pucDst = cHexDigit_to_Nibble1(*pucSrc++) << 4;
        *pucDst |= cHexDigit_to_Nibble1(*pucSrc++);
    }
}
printf("data is %s\n\n",pucDst);
}
```

but when i am trying to convert all '00' to BCD and adding this 00 to the rest of the string it's failing..when I am doing an strcat of "00" to the message then in the receiving end it is coming as "3030"

Can anybody suggest me how to encode 00 so that in  the receiving end also all corresponding 00 can be recieved.

Answer (score 2):

C strings are terminated by `00` (as you put it) so any attempt to use standard string operations like `%s` or `strcat` is going to fail.  You are going to have to operate on buffers of `char` where you maintain the length yourself (and if you need to print or send it, use the length, or iterate over it yourself one byte at a time).